# Node-edge coloring of graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology, graph-colorings

There must be work on this concept, but I am not finding it through
searches, perhaps using the wrong terminology.

---

[image: NodeEdgeColoring]

---

Define a *node-edge coloring* of a graph $G=(V,E)$
to assign an integer color to each node and edge of $G$,
such that

1. No two adjacent nodes are assigned the same color.
2. No two edges incident to the same node have the same color.
3. No edge incident to a node has the same color as that node.
   Or, equivalently, a node's color is distinct from all its incident
   edges colors.

<strike>I believe this</strike>This forces $K_4$ to have <strike>6</strike> $5$ colors
(Thanks to Fedor Petrov for the coloring.)

> ***Q***. Has this type of coloring been studied? Does it have a name
>   in the literature? Or is it instead just a combination of $G$ and the
>   [line graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LineGraph.html) of $G$
>   and so not worthy of separate study?

Comment: Perhaps a *total coloring* is what you seek?

Comment: Take 1234 cycle, diagonals 13,24 have color 5, sides 12,23,34,41 have colors 3,4,1,2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as a [total coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_coloring). It has not received a huge amount of attention in the literature, though [this](http://scholarworks.sjsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4075&context=etd_theses) masters thesis seems a good place to start.

Comment: Actually it has received some interest. The total coloring conjecture is that the total chromatic number is at most $\Delta + 2$ (maximum degree plus 2). This was conjectured by the Iranian mathematician Mehdi Behzad in the 1960s, but also appeared in the work of Vizing (note the similarity to Vizing's edge chromatic number theorem), and who has priority is in some dispute.

Comment: Is this number known for $K_n$ ( complete graph )? Gerhard "Feeling Somewhat Colorful This Day" Paseman, 2015.11.14

Comment: For the complete graph $K_n$, the total chromatic number is $n$ or $n+1$ for odd and even $n$ respectively.